# How to simulate 10000 users accessing a website for a period of 12 hours using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Using JMeter I want to simulate 10000 users that will connect to a webservice. The users will not connect at the same time but they will access the service from 08:00am to 08:00pm.

I didn't find how to do that in JMeter.

In the real life the number of concurrent users will be random (we can't predict that)

So if i'll use Ramp-up period it will not work because the number of users will be increasing gradually, which i don't want to have.

Is there a way to do this scenario in JMeter ?

And another question, i'm using JMeter v5.2 and i can't find the option Scheduler in the ThreadGroup, while in many tutorials they show that option.

Comment: Take a look at the different thread groups available, if the default choices don't get you where you need to be, you can add some plugins for the different thread groups until you likely find what you are looking for.

Comment: Can't see where to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Given this statement:

> In the real life the number of concurrent users will be random (we can't predict that)

I can only think about implementing a [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing).

["Normal" Load Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough/) is the process of putting the system under **anticipated** load and if you cannot figure out the current or expected load pattern you can only try to evenly distribute 10 000 users across 12 hours which gives 833 users per hour. There could be some "spikes" at the beginning of the day and after the lunch, but without knowing the business logic of your application it's hard to give a recommendation apart from generic [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) approach.

So you can try to identify the limits of your system you can start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load up to 10 000 or even more, until the errors start occurring or response time starts exceeding acceptable thresholds, whatever comes the first.

This way you will be able to tell what is the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and where is the first [bottleneck](https://blog.qatestlab.com/2018/04/17/testing-system-bottlenecks/)